# utf8 corrigir texto como remover caracteres estranhos

Tags: html, utf-8

Boa tarde como uso o utf8 na pagina html para remover caracteres como RefeiÃ§Ã£o que deveria ser Refeição? Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque o código abaixo dentro da sua tag `<head></head>`.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```